# SSRS First, Second, Third, etc?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

```
=First(Fields!PrimeContractor.Value, "DataSet1") + ", " + Last(Fields!PrimeContractor.Value, "DataSet1")
```

This is good to get the first and last values from a field into one single cell, but how do I get everything else in between? I tried "Second" but that is a time value so I know that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LookupSet** to get the selected values in a dataset then use **JOIN** to put them all together:

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!PrimeContractor.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

Since you want all records, use 1 and 1 for the first two arguments (1 = 1). This reads as:

> Lookup records where **1** = **1** and return the **PrimeContractor** in the **DataSet1**  Dataset.

Comment: I tried the look-up expression many times before I wrote the question and it never worked for me; I keep getting this error: "The Value expression for the text box ‘textbox14’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset." That is why I decided that maybe through First and Last I can get it to work.

Comment: @K.Ventura - Is your **DataSet1** actually **Dataset1**? Some functions are more fickle about CAPS than others.

Comment: It's called DataSet1, yes